# Можно ли сделать в Visual Studio 2019 поведение похожее на Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio

1)Автоматическая подстановка даже если пространства нет с последующем его добавлением

При использовании Resharper самое главное, что бы необходимые сборка была подцеплена к проекту. А далее выбираешь из выпадающего списка необходимый тип и он появляется в using'ах. Т.е автоподстановка работает даже тогда, когда в пространство не указано.

В Visual Studio 2019, вроде, завезли фичи автоматического добавления пространства, но работают они неудобно:
Сначала вводится название класса без каких-либо подсказок, а далее нужно нажать на лампочку и лишь тогда добавится пространство имен...

2)При форматировании развертывание анонимного типа из одной строки в несколько:
было так:

```
new { IsComplete=row.IsComplete,Error=row.Error, Id=row.Id }
```

Хочу так:

```
        new 
    { 
        IsComplete=row.IsComplete,
        Error=row.Error, 
        Id=row.Id 
     }
```

Resharper умел такое делать.

Нет ли в новой VS какой-нибудь настройки, которая бы добавила поведение похожее на Resharper?

Comment: По первому вопросу - в версии 16.2.0 они это планируют добавить.

Comment: @SultanovShamil, а есть ссылка?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/intellisense-completion-unimported-types?view=vs-2019, оказывается уже вышла с версии 16.1.0

Comment: @SultanovShamil, действительно. Только в настройках галочку поставить нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на первый вопрос, раз никто не ответил:

В Visual Studio 2019 добавили экспериментальную фичу **[IntelliSense completion for unimported types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/intellisense-completion-unimported-types?view=vs-2019)** и включается она тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге, если раньше было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе типа произойдет автоматический импорт пространства имен.

Однако, на скриншоте видно, что работает он не удобно:

1. Он ищет с середины слова, а не с начала, что на мой взгляд не есть
   гуд.
2. Не импортируются классы с методами-расширения.

Возможно, в будущем это поправят, а пока для себя я открыл вот такое бесплатное расширение - **[IntelliSense Extender 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dreamescaper.IntellisenseExtender2019&ssr=false#qna)**, который методы расширения отображает, а так же в селекторе подсвечивается наиболее похожий по названию тип. Например, если есть объект с названием `File`, то он будет первым подсвечен в выпадающем списке.